# Key to Component Mapper

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a key to component mapper but I wouldn't write all possible cases because multiple of that are the same, therefore I want a key that include all keys just not mapped.
Is it possible?

```
export const PP_ATTESTATO_DI_RISCHIO_MAP_KEY_TO_COMPONENTS: IGenericEntities<(props: any) => any> = {

"001": (props) => <Component1 {...props} />,
"034": (props) => <Component2 {...props} />,
"082": (props) => <Component3 {...props} />,

//DEFAULT CASES
[DEFAULT]: (props) => <Component4 {...props} />, 
}
```

Like you can se I have a DEFAULT key to map the Component4 rendered when the key will be "002", "003","004" and so on.
I need to change DEFAULT with something that permit me to includes all cases just not mapped.

CORRECT ANSWER:

Create a useMemo :

```
const ComponentToRender = useMemo(() => {
    return PP_ATTESTATO_DI_RISCHIO_MAP_KEY_TO_COMPONENTS[tipoMotivazione] || DefaultAttestatoDiRischioField
}, [tipoMotivazione])
```

and in the return of principle component write this:

```
 return (
         <ComponentToRender {...props}/>
 )
```

Comment: just do `!PP_ATTESTATO_DI_RISCHIO_MAP_KEY_TO_COMPONENTS[key] && (props) => <Component4 {...props} />`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a default case directly in the object like that (or maybe you can, with a Proxy, but I wouldn't recommend it).

Instead you can simply do

```
const getComponentFromKey = (key: string) => {
  return MAP_KEY_TO_COMPONENT[key] || (props) => <Component4 {...props} />
}
```

Note also that unless you are planning to add different props, you could simply use `Component1` instead of `(props) => <Component1 {...props} />`, it would probably make the code look cleaner.

Comment: It doesn't work.
I can't write  `|| (props) => <Component4 {...props} />`

Comment: Why not? Maybe you need parentheses around the function?

Comment: It is the same. I wrote `MAP_KEY_TO_COMPONENT || <Component4 {...props}/>`

Comment: But what do you mean by "I can't write"? What prevents you from writing it?